# Form input's are not showing in Firefox browser?

Tags: html, web, responsive-design, media-queries

I designing the UI for web site and i created the login and signup page. this page i can clearly see all input's in chrome browser as i design but in Firefox browser can't see that input's, It's showing like blank form. I can't understand what's that issues please advice me or give a solution how to fixed this issues? I'll upload my images for reference..

**This is Chrome Browser**

[image]

**This is for Firefox browser**

[image]

Comment: Show us what you've done for this using snippet or minimal code.

Comment: My Style CSS - http://theuniversalit.com/css/style.css

Plugin CSS - http://theuniversalit.com/css/main.min.css